# How to layout flexbox properly with larger area on top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container that I am trying to make work, and I know there are some media queries that I will have to figure out later, but I can't even seem to get the original layout to work. The idea was to have a wrapper over the top of everything to keep it within the container, and then have the "#about" flexed over to the left, and then using a ".container2" on the right side, evenly split up 2 more sections vertically (#map, and #info). Later I will work on the media queries, but I have attached a picture of what I'm more or less trying to solve. Here is my codepen as well showing what I've been able to figure out so far.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremylucas/pen/abbLPqr)

[Picture of what I'm trying to accomplish (sketch)](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/247KqPWnLKjDOZ0q1eLPPhh0Rfd1pvdFB9dRDoOhkA8RTQALloR6Yscz2AF2FuXTyl4jh6xhH7YLYFS6g27YUum7LbKfE8e0w3eLcdkXyO40pVRhrsuwyt8fIUf3f3KFTP4283Gtx8DS3_HLl7AFBAvWzHkcJOPQW-ZY3hr_sMmwurSWwtOGfaUW9HprOoiWdDG-vho3ItEZt4xydSXIJVOxvuwaLUl1KJLhMtBrChaZ_U8XCl886jTB8-TgQG-rThLHeLH9hOzf_H21IDwdGxylAHqX9fR3PRuGELV6ZGG7aH20V134unTq_hWWQ2UwppQnW60K94Qq0ATSSfhJnIGZl-sVH1yITZ7YHJVvFH28hyOR2V5ia4e6E_acVeKJzETl9uAtjJn_Bqoz2T2efyqbCa5s3m161CaJ0-OHpqTgAVpLsDJSotkxvU1tnrUwOV3P3PuP7RjlFK8Q-9u59lwtN8BL10sJRfsGZunfXtFvzLs3XuMusMDOFLY-jOw3oODL6HAdinNjFd27SUyXTdTN81xPPcfBRrtnrbCykg5KonbsW6y8zKdTHv3nzBYtAwd6tgvHHBr2yqVRmlUWxROS1obV2ZHT9EJpelLiNrqNt8hwmcODtGAwH2V6lmLpGjl4iMdTwriYJy344IV0X2fciNAluEKje06wH8MRtVWe7weTFzen6kEa=w817-h1089-no)

I apologize in advance as I feel this may be a very easy subject matter, but I just can't seem to get it to work and all the flexbox videos I've watched have got me nowhere as they don't show this type of flex.

```css
.container {
    width: 80%; 
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}
.box {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px;
  }
    #map {
        margin: auto;
        background-color: yellow;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #info {
      margin: auto;
      background-color: green;
    }

    #about {
        width: 100%;
    }
 #about {
      order: -1;
      width: 48%;
    }
.container2 {
  width: 48%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="box" id="about">
                    <h3>Company Main</h3>                    
                      <p> 
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam id tempore accusamus eaque quidem quo dicta. Quo totam dolor eius dolorem hic a fugit eligendi. <br><br>      Asperiores, iure repellendus facilis cum sapiente unde repudiandae perferendis excepturi ipsam tenetur magnam ex tempore rem fugiat, doloribus beatae consectetur impedit atque voluptates vel. <br><br> Repudiandae perspiciatis quo consectetur deserunt iusto voluptatum, cumque fugiat rem recusandae totam et cum sunt saepe neque ab delectus, modi dicta accusamus voluptatibus culpa corporis nobis. Harum cum quas eum architecto distinctio quia dolorum, ducimus optio libero suscipit hic officiis explicabo beatae ullam, molestiae repudiandae non minus consequuntur facilis quibusdam ipsa quam. <br><br> Quas assumenda tempora excepturi rerum in deleniti labore laboriosam saepe voluptates nulla quidem placeat asperiores alias fugiat numquam corrupti impedit minima, reprehenderit molestias, repellat nemo pariatur animi adipisci aspernatur. Facilis aut ipsum, atque vero voluptatum in rerum ab eum rem eos unde adipisci? <br><br> Beatae modi veritatis officia minus vero cumque a pariatur quod libero quas expedita inventore eligendi, laboriosam, id voluptatibus! Dolor nam incidunt exercitationem molestiae ea porro ipsam explicabo reiciendis necessitatibus voluptates et quidem ipsa aspernatur suscipit eos quaerat magni culpa debitis perspiciatis esse, dicta vero doloribus iste? <br><br> Consectetur culpa assumenda dolore provident voluptatem dolor eum repellat harum.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper container2">
                      <div class="box" id="map">
                        <p>      
                            hello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="box" id="info">
                        <p>  Corporate Headquarters <br>
                            XXXX Main Street <br>
                           Capital City, ST 80004 <br><br>
    
                            P.O. Box 101 <br>
                            Capital, ST 11011 <br><br>
                            
                            888.888.8888 <br>
                            Fax 888.888.8881 <br>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This fork https://codepen.io/hanna92/pen/bGGozom might be helpful, I added an extra div around the two right hand boxes, extra divs can be real helpful :)

Comment: I think this worked well, is there any good way to get rid of all the white space on the right-hand side though?

Comment: That’d probably be a case of making sure that the widths were correct and making careful use of the flex-align property ☺️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is flex basis and flex direction.

You should add a container1 class onto your first paragraph container next to box.

then update your code to reflect these changes, I removed all of your CSS and the lines below were all that was required to achive the sketch you supplied

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}

.container1{
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.container2{
    flex-basis: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Hopefully this is what you are looking for